# Phonegap, wrong innerwidth detection

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm developing an App with Phonegap, so far only on iOS, my problem is at start up:

when I launch the App in Landscape mode it gets wrong innerWidth and innerHeight values, even checking in Safari's console, it looks like it 'thinks' its in Portrait.

The weird thing is that if I launch it in Portrait and then turn it to Landscape... its works correctly.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance
Ale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like the problem was caused by a statusbar plug-in, really weird.
Anyway, once replaced it with a different one, everything now is fine.

Ale